# how to update markers on google map without refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm new with google map so i want ur help, what i'm trying to do is to update the map with the new locations without refresh the page , i'm using ajax to get locations from end point these location updated automatically but when i go to my website i have to refresh it in order to see the new locations i don't know why it doesn't work , is there any solution here is my code

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: 29.91, lng: 31.21};
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: uluru
  });


  // AJAX call to retrieve data from website
  function getinformation() {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var result = xhttp.responseText, // response in order to be repeated
                data = JSON.parse(result); // converting recieved JSON into array of objects

                console.log(data);

                var markers = [];
                    contents = [],
                    infowindows = [];

                      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: {lat: data[i].lat, lng:data[i].long}, // modified to recieve all info even status
                              map: map,
                              animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                            });

                            
                            markers[i].index = i;
                            contents[i] = '<div class="popup_container" style="padding: 5px">' + data[i].status +'</div>';

                            console.log(markers);
                            infowindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contents[i],
                            maxWidth: 300
                            });

                            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
                                    console.log(this.index); // this will give correct index
                                    console.log(i); //this will always give 10 for you
                                    infowindows[this.index].open(map,markers[this.index]);
                                    map.panTo(markers[this.index].getPosition());
                            });
                      }

            }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", 'api/v1/record/all', true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
  getinformation();
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to refresh page, simply clear map and relocate marker
map.clear() you can use and then relocate marker position on map, where you getting new location.

Hope it will help!!

Comment: thanx for your help but if u don't mind could u please modify my code because i'm confused from this new api